# What do I need `setTimeout(resolve)` in my JavaScript data-loading promise?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-promise

I am trying to grok ES6 Promises by not just getting simple example code from howto articles to work, but actually trying to implement the concepts learned into code that could be useful some way in an actual project.

Below I created code in frontend Vue.js/axios which successfully uses Promises to load five areas of the screen with data. In my backend `loadData` action, I have it artificually wait one second so I can see that the each of the five areas of the screen load with data in one second intervals:

```
<div id="app" class="pageContent">
    <div>Data 1: {{data1}}</div>
    <div>Data 2: {{data2}}</div>
    <div>Data 3: {{data3}}</div>
    <div>Data 4: {{data4}}</div>
    <div>Data 5: {{data5}}</div>
</div>
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            data1: 'loading...',
            data2: 'loading...',
            data3: 'loading...',
            data4: 'loading...',
            data5: 'loading...'
        },
        methods: {
            initialize: function () {
                const that = this;
                this.loadData('data1')
                    .then(() => {
                        return that.loadData('data2');
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        return that.loadData('data3');
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        return that.loadData('data4');
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        return that.loadData('data5');
                    });
            },
            loadData: function (idCode) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const that = this;
                    axios({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: 'controllerShowcaseLoadDataWithPromises',
                        data: {
                            action: 'loadData',
                            idCode: idCode
                        }
                    }).then(function (responseObject) {
                        const response = qsys.getResponse(responseObject);
                        that[idCode] = response.data.message;
                        setTimeout(resolve);
                    });
                });
            },
        }
    });
    app.initialize();
```

While this seems to work fine, can anyone explain why I have to use `setTimeout(resolve)` (without it, the code only executes once) and what is actually going here? I understand that this is the basically the way to `execute a callback` as we used to do it before promises, but what is a cleaner, more standard way to do this?

Comment: What are the alternative ways to make it work you used before `setTimeout(resolve)` ?

Comment: Using a dummied-up axios, I don't see any problems with calling `resolve` immediately - all divs get populated sequentially, whether I use `resolve()` or `setTimeout(resolve)`? Unless your alternative is not calling `resolve` at all, in which case the problem is clear, you have to call `resolve` when using the Promise constructor for its constructed Promise to resolve, else it'll hang forever

Comment: Couple of bad practices here: `axios` returns a `Promise` and you are wrapping the `Promise` with your own `Promise` with no good reason. Using `function` instead of an `arrow function` makes you need to create the `that` variable instead of gaining leverage of the closure. In your case `setTimeout(resolve)` is useless.  In the `initialize` method, use `Promise.all` instead of the chained `then's` - there is no dependency between the calls and then can run asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...why I have to use `setTimeout(resolve)`

You don't have to use `setTimeout`, but you do have to call `resolve` (or `reject`) in order to settle the promise.

> what is actually going here?

You're doing a series of asynchronous calls, waiting for the previous one to complete before doing the next, because of the way you've chained the promises together. That's why if you don't resolve the first one, none of the others runs: You've chained your operations so that in each case, the next one only runs if the previous operation was successfully completed. If you don't call `resolve`, although the operation completed, you never settle the promise you created letting the code using that promise that the operation completed.

> I understand that this is the basically the way to execute a callback as we used to do it before promises, but what is a cleaner, more standard way to do this?

Calling `resolve` is the standard way if you have to explicitly create a promise. **But**, you don't have to in this case, because you already have a promise from `axios`. So `loadData` should be:

```
loadData: function(idCode) {
    return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'controllerShowcaseLoadDataWithPromises',
        data: {
            action: 'loadData',
            idCode: idCode
        }
    }).then(function (responseObject) {
        const response = qsys.getResponse(responseObject);
        this[idCode] = response.data.message;
    });
},
```

Notice that it returns the result of calling `then` on the promise from `axios`. (Also note that since you're using arrow functions, you don't need the `that = this` thing. Arrow functions *close over* `this`.)

If you want your operations done one after another, then your promise chain is how you do that, although you can write it more concisely if you like and you should be handling errors (and again, don't need `that = this`):

```
this.loadData('data1')
    .then(() => this.loadData('data2'))
    .then(() => this.loadData('data3'))
    .then(() => this.loadData('data4'))
    .then(() => this.loadData('data5'))
    .catch(error => {
        // handle/report error here
    });
```

If you want those five operations done *in parallel* (overlapping), you can start them all right away and use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to complete:

```
Promise.all([
    this.loadData('data1'),
    this.loadData('data2'),
    this.loadData('data3'),
    this.loadData('data4'),
    this.loadData('data5'),
])
.catch(error => {
    // handle/report error here
});
```

Finally, depending on your target browsers and whether you want to transpile, you can also use `async` functions and `await`:

```
loadData: async function(idCode) {
    const responseObject = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'controllerShowcaseLoadDataWithPromises',
        data: {
            action: 'loadData',
            idCode: idCode
        }
    });
    const response = qsys.getResponse(responseObject);
    this[idCode] = response.data.message;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

A 'cleaner' way of doing what you are doing now is adding all the promises to an array, and using `Promise.all`:

```
const requests = [
    that.loadData('data1'),
    that.loadData('data2'),
    that.loadData('data3'),
    that.loadData('data4'),
    that.loadData('data5')
];

Promise.all(requests).then(value => {
    // All resolved values in order
}).catch(error => {
    // Error
});
```

The reason your `loadData` function is only executing once when you don't `resolve` the promise is exactly because you are not resolving the promise. `then` is never executed in your chain.

There is no need to wrap `resolve` in `setTimeout`.